# Geolocation asking for multiple permission requests inside a TWA

Tags: javascript, android-studio, geolocation, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I am fairly new to coding so this might be noob question..

I have created a PWA and am launching it as a TWA from within android studio then publishing the app to the play store.

There is a Geolocation feature in the PWA that determine the users location when they press a specific button.

```
var result;

function showPosition() {
    
    result = document.getElementById("result");
    
    
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
        result.innerHTML = "Getting the position information...";
    } else {
        alert("Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 geolocation.");
    }
};


function successCallback(position) {
    result.innerHTML = "Your current position is (" + "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", " + "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude + ")";
}
```

I have set up the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions in android studio and this will sucessully prompt the user for permissions when the app first launches.

This is in my android manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and this is in the main activity:

```
 private static final String[] GPS_PERMISSIONS = {
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};


private void verifyPermissions() {

    int permissionGps = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    int permissionInternet = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET);

    if (permissionGps != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                MainActivity.this,
                GPS_PERMISSIONS,
                1

        );
```

This issue I face is that is is asking the user twice for location permissions.

Permissions are asked the first time when the app launches (the native prompt)

[image: Native prompt screenshot]

then again when they press the button in the TWA (the HTML5 prompt)

[image: PWA prompt screenshot]

Is it possible to share/pass the permissions from the native app to the TWA so all permissions are handled within the native app and user does not need to approve again once inside a TWA?

Comment: Is it asking the second time if the user has turned off location for the device? If so, then I think that is working as designed. If the user says off, the browser respects that.

Comment: I did some further research and looks like what I need is "Geolocation delegation". This will pass permissions from a native app into the TWA. However, it appears that this feature is still under development by Google and has not been fully released yet.. Guess I will just have to wait until they release it to include in my app

https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa/issues/60

Answer (score 2):

Location Delegation is now stable and this shouldn't be an issue anymore. Check out the [demo app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/tree/master/demos/twa-location-delegation) on how to use it. If this behaviour persists, please file a bug at https://crbug.com